# how to wrap several files into the same namespace in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, preprocessor-directive

In C# it's simple to put all of the classes into an unique namespace. I understand how a namespace works in C++ at a simple level. But when comes to put many files together to appear as one namespace I get really confused.
It is something like this possible:

```
/* NetTools.cpp
blade 7/12/2014 */
using namespace std;
using namespace NetTools;
#include "NetTools.h"

int main()
{
   cout << "testing" << endl;
   return 0;
}
//####### EOF
```

---

```
/* NetTools.h 
blade 12/7/2014 */

#ifndef NETTOOLS_H
#define NETTOOLS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

namespace NetTools
{

}

#endif
// #### EOF
```

---

```
/* Commands.h
blade 7/12/2014 */

#include "NetTools.h"
#ifndef COMMANDS_H
#define COMMANDS_H

namespace NetTools
{

}

#endif
// ###### EOF
```

---

I'm separating every class declaration in its .h file and the implementation in its cpp file, but I want everything to be in the same namespace.

Comment: If you put declarations appearing in different header files into the same namespace, they'll share it. I don't get what's your actual problem. Also note, you should include stuff within your include guards, not outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've shown works fine.

One fundamental property of namespaces is that if different files all declare things in a namespace with the same name, the compiler/linker know to put things together so you get one namespace containing everything that was defined in it from all the files.

For example:

```
// file a
namespace A {
    class X;
}

// file b
namespace A {
    class Y;
}

// file c
namespace A {
    class Z;
}
```

...is mostly equivalent to:

```
// one file
namespace A {
    class X;
    class Y;
    class Z;
}
```

The exception to this is anonymous namespaces. Anonymous namespaces are separated per-file. For example:

```
// file a
namespace {
    void f();
}

// file b
namespace {
    int f();
}
```

These don't conflict because each file has its own, unique anonymous namespace.

Comment: I think here "files" should be read as "translation-units", as the f() in the unnamed namespace(s) in file a and file b declare the same function when file a and file b are #included in the same translation-unit.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct. There is a problem with your code here though:

```
/* NetTools.cpp
blade 7/12/2014 */
using namespace std;
using namespace NetTools; // put this AFTER #include "NetTools.h"
#include "NetTools.h"

int main()
{
   cout << "testing" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

It works for `using namespace std;` *(not sure why)* but it won't work for namespaces *you* declare. The compiler needs to see them *before* you can start `using` them:

```
/* NetTools.cpp
blade 7/12/2014 */
#include "NetTools.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace NetTools; // now this should work

int main()
{
   cout << "testing" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**Sidenote:**

You should really put *everything* inside the include guard:

```
/* Commands.h
blade 7/12/2014 */

#include "NetTools.h" // this should really go after the include guards
#ifndef COMMANDS_H
#define COMMANDS_H

namespace NetTools
{

}

#endif
```

There is no need to `#include "NetTools.h"` twice *(even if it is include protected)*.

```
/* Commands.h
blade 7/12/2014 */

#ifndef COMMANDS_H
#define COMMANDS_H

#include "NetTools.h" // like this

namespace NetTools
{

}

#endif
```